# Solr - How to highlight specific terms in specific fields

Tags: solr, lucene, highlight

How can i highlight a specif term in a specif field?

For example, imagine the following query:

```
foo TITLE("bar")
```

, what i want to achieve is the highlight of `foo` in all fields and `bar` only in the field `TITLE`.

Until now the following has not worked:

```
q=<TITLE_field_internal_name>:"bar"hl.fl=&&hl.requireFieldMatch=true
```

Note: In the above example `TITLE` is re-mapped correctly to a solr field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most highlighting parameters supports the per-field parameter syntax:

```
f.TITLE.hl.<parameter>
```

Seeing as your syntax isn't valid Solr syntax and there is no way it'll know that `TITLE("bar")` refers to a field named TITLE, you'll have to extract that (or provide) that metadata yourself.

If you're querying different fields and only want to highlight the terms hit in those fields (i.e. if your query had been `title:bar` to only search for `bar` in the field `title`), you don't have to use per field settings, but can set `hl.requireFieldMatch` to `true` instead.

> By default, false, all query terms will be highlighted for each field to be highlighted (hl.fl) no matter what fields the parsed query refer to. If set to true, only query terms aligning with the field being highlighted will in turn be highlighted.
>
> Note: if the query references fields different from the field being highlighted and they have different text analysis, the query may not highlight query terms it should have and vice versa. The analysis used is that of the field being highlighted (hl.fl), not the query fields.

Comment: In the above example i'm able to programmatically map `TITLE` to know solr field.

Comment: Sure, then you can use either requireFieldMatch or give a custom parameter for each field type you want to perform highlighting on.

Comment: But "you don't have to use per field settings, but can set hl.requireFieldMatch to true instead." is not enough as i want to highlight only `foo` in the `title` field and `bar` in the, lets say, `description ` field. But at the same time i dont want to highlight `bar` in a title containing `foo bar` where i have a query `TITLE(foo) bar`.

Comment: 'or give a custom parameter for each field type you want to perform highlighting on.' could you share an example of such sintaxe?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after much trial and error, i managed to have this thing working Here are a few snippets:

```
fq=(_query_:"{!edismax+qf%3D'container_title_en'+v%3D'hormones'}"+OR+_query_:"{!edismax+qf%3D$fqf+v%3D'cancer'}")

fqf=authors_tnss+etc+etc+...

hl.q=(_query_:"{!edismax+qf%3D'container_title_en'+v%3D'hormones'}"+OR+_query_:"{!edismax+qf%3D$fqf+v%3D'cancer'}")

hl.fl=id,external_id_s,etc,etc,...

hl.requireFieldMatch=true
```

, notice that if `hl.fl` fields are separated by `,` and in my custom `fqf` field in `fq` they are separated by `+`.